# Getting 2 ERROR Messeges Eclipse compiler: non static member and error 2

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am new to C++, I have been doing tasks for training. This task was to make a calculation while using class and accessing private integer.

here is my full code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Calculatour{

public:

int SumNum(int a, int b){

    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;

    x = a+b;

    return x;
}




private:

int x;

};


int main() {

Calculatour ADD;

cout << ADD.SumNum;

return 0;
}
```

I have been getting an error on this line:

```
cout << ADD.SumNum;
```

Where it says

reference to non-static member function must be called  ADD calculatour using classes.cpp   /ADD calculatour using classes/src  line 37 C/C++ Problem.

Also I have been getting this error too:

make: *** [src/ADD calculatour using classes.o] Error 1 ADD calculatour using classes           C/C++ Problem

Please consider that i am new to the language. So if you can provide a solution and an explanation this would be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: What did you hope `cout << ADD.SumNum;` would do?

Comment: i was hoping it activates the function, where i will have to enter a, b and then its gonna save it in the X variable which is in the private variable list @IInspectable

Comment: Where are you passing parameters to the `SumNum` method?  I turned on the "magic" setting on my compiler so it will read my mind.

Comment: Indeed I think he found yet another missing feature of iostream!!!

Comment: `cout << ADD.SumNum(0,0);` would make this compile and in fact do the addition, but I warn you that this is not the proper solution to the bigger issue in your code.

Comment: A pity c++ has no reflection. Then this could really be a feature. Reflect on the function passed, find out it has 2 parameters of int. Cin user for them. Invoke. Print. EzPz :)

Comment: ok so i should learn all of these now and alter the code to fix it. then should i report it? or what people?!? lol @BitTickler

Comment: @BitTickler That sounds absolutely loathsome, as we would have to start declaring functions `explicit` left right and centre to prevent accidentally invoking this behaviour.

Comment: You mean people would complain when someone turned a huge mess into an infinitesimally huger mess? :)

Comment: ok.... Am I getting an answer or not?

Comment: What? You're not happy with spawning an interesting conversation on C++ parameter inference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When invoking a method (or calling a function) with parameters one must supply the parameters even if they are not used. Since in this method you have no intention of using the parameters for anything and have no class hierarchy that forces you to include these parameters, you may as well discard them.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Calculatour
{
public:
    int SumNum()
    {
        int a;
        int b;
        cin >> a;
        cin >> b;

        x = a + b;

        return x;
    }

private:
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    Calculatour ADD;
    cout << ADD.SumNum();
    return 0;
}
```

The more ideologically correct solution (the Calculator class should do Calculator things, not Data In/Out things) would be to read a and b in in main, and then call SumNum.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Calculatour
{
public:
    int SumNum(int a, int b)
    {
        x = a + b;
        return x;
    }
    int SumNum(int a) // takes advantage of the stored x value
    {
        x += a;
        return x;
    }
private:
    int x = 0;
};

int main()
{
    Calculatour ADD;
    int a;
    int b;

    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;

    cout << ADD.SumNum(a, b);
    cout << ADD.SumNum(a);
    return 0;
}
```

There is no way for the compiler to tell

```
int SumNum()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;

    x = a + b;

    return x;
}
```

from

```
int SumNum()
{
    int a;
    cin >> a;

    x += a;

    return x;
}
```

so you cannot take advantage of overloading and having the same method name perform different tasks with different input.

Say you want

```
double SumNum()
{
    double a;
    double b;
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;

    return a + b;
}
```

to take floating point input. You can't. You'd have to change the method's name or use templates.

Comment: thank you for your answer. i went with the first method where the whole function will be in one line. 

where calling the function will ask the user for the value and then calculate it.

Comment: I caution on going that route. It can lead to future disadvantages. I will edit the answer to demonstrate one.

Comment: well i think i kinda get you. you mean i can't get double and int from the same method and yes i understand this. but it is still foggy so i will try studying it more. thank you again.